# OleDb Parameters, null value

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I have the following code,

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",conn);

    OleDbParameter p1 = new OleDbParameter();
    OleDbParameter p2 = new OleDbParameter();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
    p1.Value = usernametb.Text;
    p2.Value = passwordtb.Text;

    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (read.Read() == true)
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in!");
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
        }
```

This code works for me if the user has a password, but if the user does not have a password, then it fails and I don't know why.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where you are getting the Error exactly and what is the issue.? :) I guess here `p2.Value = passwordtb.Text;` and error is object reference... Correct.?

Answer (score 1):

It is because in SQL standard `null = null` returns `null` instead of `true`.

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND (password is null or password = ?)
```

A better query would be to check that when the password is `null` the user must enter an empty password so it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND 
    ? = case when password is null then '' else password end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND 
                          (password IS NULL OR password = ?)
```